# Pass value from view to controller using DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to pass a model's value from view to controller.

When I use `@Html.TextBoxFor`, the value gets to the controller, but when I use `@Html.DisplayFor`, the value is `null` in the controller.

**`View.cshtml`**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditView", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) // 1st way

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name) // 2nd way

    <input type="submit" value="Ok !" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
}
```

**`Controller`**

```
public ActionResult EditView(ModelList model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Basically, the 1st time the controller gets the value; but the 2nd time, it gets `null`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What type is `model.Name`?

Comment: in model.Name, model is a Model and model.Name is Name variable of model(ModelList)

Comment: Is it a `string` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor` just displays the value in the view.

If you want the value to be passed back to the controller on post then you also need a `@Html.HiddenFor`